# How to make a custom file upload handle in django to handle large files without using MemoryFileUploadHandler and TemporaryFileUploadHandler

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

everyone
I have been working on building a reels type feature using django and exploring various methods. Initially the best way I found to handle large files is to do the uploading of files directly to files to the s3 directly. But I am trying to find a way through the server without increasing load on it much.

So django uses 2 image handles - MemoryFileUploadHandler and TemporaryFileUploadHandler based on the image size which stores file into memory or disk temporarily. I want to make a custom handler that will directly store the files into s3 with using the memory or disk of the server. Not sure if it is possible. Even if we do it by chunks, it will read the file which ultimately get stored in server for sometime.

I am looking for a more feasible way to make a custom file handler to directly upload chunks to s3 without writing or reading it into the system. I am not sure it is possible. If you have any workaround I should go for, I would be of great help.

Sharing the code I am trying but at each point, I either have to use the above handlers.

```
import boto3

class S3ChunkedUploadHandler:
    def __init__(self, upload_path, filename):
        self.upload_path = upload_path
        self.filename = filename
        self.file = open(upload_path, 'ab')

    def receive_data_chunk(self, raw_data, start):
        self.file.write(raw_data)

    def file_complete(self, file_size):
        self.file.close()
        self.upload_to_s3()

    def upload_to_s3(self):
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
        with open(self.upload_path, 'rb') as file:
            s3_client.upload_fileobj(file, AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, self.filename)
```

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .custom_uploaders import S3ChunkedUploadHandler

class FileUploadView(APIView):
    def put(self, request, format=None):
        upload_path = '/tmp/uploaded_file.dat'  # Specify the temporary file path
        desired_filename = 'uploaded_file.dat'  # Specify the desired filename
        upload_handler = S3ChunkedUploadHandler(upload_path, desired_filename)
        request.upload_handlers.insert(0, upload_handler)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I have to get the temp file from somewhere stored in system. then what's the use of custom uploaders.

As Django Docs states - "You can write custom handlers that customize how Django handles files. You could, for example, use custom handlers to enforce user-level quotas, compress data on the fly, render progress bars, and even send data to another storage location directly without storing it locally. See Writing custom upload handlers for details on how you can customize or completely replace upload behavior."

Answer (score 0):

If you're implementing your own chunked writer you have to actually connect to S3 during the chunked writes. As your code stands it is creating a file, writing the chunked connections to the file, and then attempting the upload to S3 which isn't direct.

Perhaps you should [check this article about how to use django-storages to do the direct upload](https://www.hacksoft.io/blog/direct-to-s3-file-upload-with-django)

Or you could start by taking a look at this project which [claims to handle S3 uploads directly](https://github.com/bradleyg/django-s3direct)

There are lots of things to consider when directly pushing the file to s3 including but not limited to security policies and region selection. At the end of the day they do use a chunked file upload strategy but there's a reason these are entire projects the community is working on.

For code examples of the chunked writers you can look [here](https://github.com/uktrade/django-chunk-s3-av-upload-handlers/blob/master/django_chunk_upload_handlers/s3.py#L74) and [here](https://github.com/uktrade/django-chunk-s3-av-upload-handlers/blob/master/django_chunk_upload_handlers/s3.py#L126)